# Where can I redirect exploit scanning bots?

Tags: redirects, web-crawlers, security, botattack

I get a lot of those exploit scanning bots like the ones looking for a WordPress login (which I don't have) or guessing other exploitable URLs.

Where is a sensible place to redirect them to via .htaccess - is there some URL that can slow them down or analyse their IP? I've tried a honeypot quick link but that seems to have failed after 1 day.

Comment: Redirecting them is unlikely to do anything.  I've been doing it for years, but I have no evidence that it slows them down in the least.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But if there was a way to take up process CPU on their machine rather than CPU on my hosting box, that's got to be a good thing., surely. I just can't see the alternative being anything other than ugly - ie a redirect loop with 60s delays each time. I'm sure these guys would easily bom,b my machine if I did that :(

Comment: @Johan trust me on this - Do not mess with these people.  If you do your server will be DDOSed for days.  I did it once, nowadays no matter how clever I think I might be, I think twice and ignore or delete.

Comment: My personal favorite is to redirect the request to the domain or IP address making the request. Makes me laugh.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to prevent bad bots from scanning your website(s). I think you should do it from htaccess. It will prevent bad scanning bots for visiting your website and return a 403 Forbidden. you can block them according to their User agent. The first line means that it will block a vistor without user agent:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (badbot|badbot1|badbot2) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [R=404,L]
```

In your logs, you can spot HTTP user agents from bad bots and add it to this list.

Comment: I think a 403 invite the bot to take another change (poke around) because it found something that is forbidden to access. 403 indicates 'something important is there'. I send a 404 and this normally reduces the amount of request however there are also some evil ones that use a poke list and don't care about errorcodes.